# Two phase sampling method for stratification

Tags: self-study, sampling, survey-sampling

**Question:**

$\$3000$ is allocated for a survey estimated proportion. The main survey will cost $\$10$ per sampling unit. Information is available in files, at a cost \$0.25 per sampling unit, that enable the units to be classified into two strata of about equal size. If the true proportion is 0.2 in stratum 1 and 0.8 in stratum 2, estimate the optimum $n$, $n’$ and the resulting value of $V(p_{st})$. Does double sampling produce a gain in precision over simple random sampling?

So in this problem, I summarize the problem like this: $C$ =total cost =\$3000, $c_1$=cost in the first phase = \$0.25 and $c_2$ = cost in the second phase = \$10.

The formula:
$C=c_1 n' + \sum_{h=1}^2 c_h  n_h$

(since strata are equal in size $c_h =c$ and $n_h = 0.5n$)

I substitute the  value in and get:

$C = c_1 n' + c n$ or 3000 = 0.25*n' + 10*n. Then I dont know how to go from there.

Comment: There are multiple conceptual problems with this. This is not a two-phase sample; a two-phase sample is when you take a subsample of the first-stage sample (e.g. by identifying a population of interest, and sampling from these). So either you are confused, or, worse, your instructor is confused (which is worse).

Comment: Also, the meaning of $n$ and $n'$ has not been defined in your question, so it literally is unanswerable. Please go back to the question and edit. DO NOT REPLY IN COMMENTS, that does not help others answer your question.

Comment: n' is the number of observations of  when we take a first phase sampling of n' elements from a population via Simple Random Sampling.

Comment: So here the procedure, say I sampling 15 people from a population via SRS, so n'=20. And then I randomly divide those 20 people into 2 Strata, 9 say n'_{1}=9 and n'_{2}=6. And then I allocate the sampled elements (9 and 6) to the h = 1, 2 strata (think of it as substrata), now n_{1}=(9/15)*5=3 and n_{2}=(6/15)*5=2. So n = 5 total. In the problem, apparently they said " two strata of about equal size", so n_{1}=n_{2} = n/2

Comment: Please put this back into the question instead of to the replies.

Answer (score -1):

${S}_{1}^2=0.8\times 0.2={S}_{2}^2=0.16$

${S^2}=0.5\times 0.5=0.25$

$W_{1}=W_{2}=0.5$

Comment: yes , double is more precise